# How can I deploy revel web app on Openshift?

Tags: go, revel

I tried to searching on some of guides on internet, but actually could not deploy revel app on Openshift successfully. I wonder why does not have any guidance to deploy revel app (step by step) on revel group or any related one. Anyone used to deployed it, please give me a hand.

Comment: Go is not officially supported by Openshift, but there are various third-party solutions available (such as this one: https://github.com/gcmurphy/golang-openshift), albeit some of them seem a bit outdated. Which one have you tried? If these work with a "vanilla" go app, they should work just as well with an app that uses the revel framework.

Comment: I think I will go for go app on Openshift, because some of customize from Revel make it hard to host on Openshift

Comment: With the link from @rob74 and instructions for building locally at http://revel.github.io/manual/deployment.html you should be able to get Revel running on OpenShift. If you do, please share your experience for the benefit of others!